# Inconsistencies between node's `spawn` and terminal

Tags: node.js, spawn, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

I'm trying to run a script from node, and I'm seeing different behaviour compared to if I run it from the terminal and I don't understand why.

I'm trying to do something a little bit out there, in that to save people typing `pnpm {scriptName} --filter {packageName}` I created a little script that they could run instead. It basically takes `scriptName` and lists all the available packages they can select from, and then trigger spawns a new process calling that command. Something like:

`spawn("pnpm", ["--filter " + packageName, scriptName], { stdio: "inherit" });`

Example:

[image]

In my particular case, I'm trying to test a script that ends up generating a `pnpm --filter @ig/main test:debug`.

I'm struggling a little though, in that if I invoke that via a terminal it works fine (test:debug is defined both in `.\package.json` and `.\apps\main\package.json`). However if I invoke it via the spawn command in node, then for some reason it invoking the `test:debug` script in the root, rather than just in `apps/main`. Does anyone know what that might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was down to the current working directory not being set correctly when using `spawn`.